# Why am I getting this "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '…' on a null object reference" error?

Tags: android

This is my java file in which I declare textView with proper id.

```
     @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.menu_wrong_answer);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout)item.getActionView();
        txt_wrong_answer=(TextView)constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt_wrong_answer);
        txt_wrong_answer.setText(String.valueOf(0));


        return true;
    }
```

This is the xml file in which I declare textview with proper id.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_wrong_answer"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_bg"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

at

`com.developers.a_g.androidquizapp.QusetionActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(QusetionActivity.java:358)`

Comment: could you post menu_wrong_answer xml file codes

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_wrong_answer"
        android:title="Wrong Answer"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/rectangle_text_view"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_finish_game"
        android:title="Finish Game"
        app:showAsAction="always"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp"/>
</menu>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could modify menu in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method, but you should create it firstly in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

Edited:

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/rectangle_text_view"
```

should be

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/rectangle_text_view"
```

Comment: i paste that code in onCreateOption but no use of it

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem register = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

have you tried `txt_wrong_answer=(TextView)constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt_wrong_answer);`
 inside oncreateOptinsMenu